# Need Oracle Client for .NET 4.0 ASP app running on a 64bit OS

Tags: asp.net, oracle, .net-4.0, 64-bit, odp.net

I've got ASP.NET 4.0 application running on a 64bit OS.  IIS is configured to run in 64bit mode (needs to be to support other ASP.NET applications).  Is there any way to do this? Oracle doesn't provide a 64bit client as of this writing for .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [ODP.NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) and especially the [64-bit driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html)?

Comment: I have. But there isn't a 64bit driver for the 4.0 framework. There is one in the works, but it had a release date of Nov 2010 and then that got moved to Mid-Dec 2010. It's now mid-Dec 2010 but nothing yet.  I was just wondering if there are other options available.